# Spring cloud contract stub jar as a http rest endpoint

Tags: docker, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to setup Spring contract stub jar as either a fat jar with consumer or a http REST endpoint that my services can send request to and eventually receive the evaluated response.

Ideally I'd prefer the latter where consumer could run the stub to manage the interactions. My tests from consumer to local producer stubs work as expected. My compilation fails when I add the required annotations to the main class for stub runner. I think I'm missing some config or setup needed for the consumer to run the stub either as http REST endpoint or recognize within its m2.

The app compilation fails with @EnableStubRunnerServer complaining the below:

```
ConsumerApplication.java:[8,60] package org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.server does not exist
ConsumerApplication.java:[15,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class EnableStubRunnerServer
```

ConsumerApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@Slf4j

public class ConsumerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties (Consumer):

```
stubrunner.ids=com.somecompany.somegroup:producer:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:stubs:8081
stubrunner.stubsMode=REMOTE
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
server.port=8081
```

Test.java: - This test works

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@AutoConfigureStubRunner( ids = "com.somecompany.somegroup:producer:+:stubs:8081", 
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
@DirtiesContext
public class ContractControllerTest extends AbstractTest {

}
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to add test code to your main, production code, you have to change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
</dependency>
```